# what determines the default font to display in a browser?

Tags: css, fonts, cross-browser, operating-system, font-family

I wanted to know the default behavior of the browser when it comes to fonts. if the CSS does not specify the `font-family` property (or it is specified, but the font is not installed) then what determines the default font?

are there fonts that are universal among OS's (times new roman, arial, etc...) or is it a universal font type (san-saraf,saraf, etc...) that all OS"s share (meaning a default will fallback to font type and not a specific font)?

Comment: Google query "cross browser font" points among the top articles to [W3Schools: CSS Web Safe Font Combinations](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_websafe_fonts.asp). You can easily learn more about the subject using Google. Voting -1 for no research effort shown

Comment: @xmojmr actually i did search for it, but did not find much. that's why I why i'm asking the question. read the question again and you'll see that I wasn't just asking about web safe font stacks I was asking what determines a default (or what will the default be) if a font/stack is not defined which is why I accepted the question below

Comment: @zero I see your point, but if you'd use my suggested Google query the Google suggests another related search "default html fonts" which points among the top articles to [W3C: Fonts → 15.2 Font matching algorithm](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/fonts.html#algorithm) which says "_..If there is no font within the family selected in 2, then use a UA-dependent default 'font-family' and repeat step 2.._". I'd recommend you to read the whole chapter. Both `W3Schools` and `W3C` are standardization bodies which should be consulted first (always) using search and research technique before asking a question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to this question depends on the users browser. Each browser has a default font. The user can then change this value to some other more desirable font to be defaulted in case of no font-family tags or no font installed on site. But it is browser specific.

Comment: so font types are universal among OS's? meaning you should target a font type (sans-serif) as well as a particular font (calibri, arial, etc...)?

Comment: I attached a link that has some great examples and an explanation of universally accepted fonts. They are broken down into three broad groups - Serif, Sans-Serif, and MonoSpaced Fonts. Serif example is Georgia, Times New Roman. Sans-Serif examples - Arial, Veranda, and more. MonoSpaced font examples - Courier New, Lucinda. There are more examples and explanation found here:  [link](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_websafe_fonts.asp)